# Merge two consecutive rows of event with start and end status

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this :

| Date | Atomic Timestamp | MAUI | Measurement Name | Operation Type | Measurement Type | Measurement Context | Measurement Action | Machine | Measurement | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-03 | 14:38:38.194376 | 7000001 | PJ_DBO_KPI_380 | 0 | NaN | NaN | StartJob | 380 | Job | Start |
| 2021-10-03 | 14:38:38.836202 | 9200031 | PJ_DBO_KPI_380 | 0 | NaN | NaN | StartReportServiceCreate | 380 | ReportServiceCreate | Start |
| 2021-10-03 | 14:38:39.058186 | 9200032 | PJ_DBO_KPI_380 | 0 | NaN | NaN | FinishReportServiceCreate | 380 | ReportServiceCreate | Finish |
| 2021-10-03 | 14:38:39.089658 | 1000001 | PJ_DBO_KPI_380 | 1 | NaN | NaN | StartPickFromCarrier | 380 | PickFromCarrier | Start |
| 2021-10-03 | 14:38:39.165627 | 3000402 | PJ_DBO_KPI_380 | 1 | NaN | NaN | StartWaferAlignLoadPatterns | 380 | WaferAlignLoadPatterns | Start |
| 2021-10-03 | 15:53:50.330514 | 9200009 | PJ_MPS_ARO | 0 | NaN | NaN | StartReportsCollection | 1385 | ReportsCollection | Start |
| 2021-10-03 | 15:53:50.330540 | 9200010 | PJ_MPS_ARO | 0 | NaN | NaN | FinishReportsCollection | 1385 | ReportsCollection | Finish |
| 2021-10-03 | 15:53:50.331217 | 9200011 | PJ_MPS_ARO | 0 | NaN | NaN | StartReplayDataCollection | 1385 | ReplayDataCollection | Start |
| 2021-10-03 | 15:53:50.331243 | 9200012 | PJ_MPS_ARO | 0 | NaN | NaN | FinishReplayDataCollection | 1385 | ReplayDataCollection | Finish |
| 2021-10-03 | 15:53:53.363365 | 9200002 | PJ_MPS_ARO | 0 | NaN | NaN | FinishReporting_155 | 1385 | Reporting_155 | Finish |

I'm looking for a way to merge all the rows which have the same measurement and the action having a start and end. Exclude all the rows if that event is not finished corresponding to the previous start activity.

Output should be like this :

| Start DT | End DT | MAUI.x | MAUI.y | Measurement Name | Operation Type | Measurement Type | Measurement Context | Machine | Measurement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-03 14:38:38.836202 | 2021-10-03 14:38:39.058186 | 9200031 | 9200032 | PJ_DBO_KPI_380 | 0 | NaN | NaN | 380 | ReportServiceCreate |
| 2021-10-03 15:53:50.330514 | 2021-10-03 15:53:50.330540 | 9200009 | 9200010 | PJ_MPS_ARO | 0 | NaN | NaN | 1385 | ReportsCollection |
| 2021-10-03 15:53:50.331217 | 2021-10-03 15:53:50.331243 | 9200011 | 9200012 | PJ_MPS_ARO | 0 | NaN | NaN | 1385 | ReplayDataCollection |

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the merge, you could simply define new datasets with start and finishing events, and merge those. Assuming `df` is your dataframe:

```
start_df = df[df.Action == "Start"]
# build the Start DT column
start_df["Start DT"] = start_df.Date.str.cat(start_df["Atomic Timestamp"])

finish_df = df[df.Action == "Finish"]
# build the End DT column
finish_df["End DT"] = finish_df.Date.str.cat(finish_df["Atomic Timestamp"])

merged = start_df.merge(finish_df, on=["Measurement"])
```

There, you'll have one dataframe with only measurements that have started and finished. You can then just drop the unused columns and reorder them as you like

Comment: I have already tried this approach. However, the Measurement is not unique, and it will keep repeating when having the same measurement, same for MAUI columns. Therefore, it will cause an error since the values are duplicated. If there is any way I can merge only the same measurement which has the start and the end of that measurement?

Comment: @LinhHoang could you maybe add more rows with repeating measurements to understand better the problem?